# Where do the section input fields values are stored in database

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, database

```
 register_setting('Y-sidebar-options','picture');
```

where do the option group name stored in database .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option group (1st param to [register_setting()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/)) is **not** stored anywhere.  The only use for option groups is to output a couple of hidden fields and a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces), via a call to [settings_fields()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_fields/).

Answer (score 0):

The options which you store by using the function register_setting is saved in table wp_options.

Comment: I Had searched the Wp_options but found nothing is does it create a column

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `add_setting('Y-sidebar-options'…);` call. Settings go into the wp_options table and can be either under a field by it's own name or else a `theme_mod` (default).

Pls also see: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting